# Что за синтаксис с двойной запятой в цикле for в старом Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Открыл какой-то старый код на Swift (наверное Swift 1). В нем ошибками подсвечиваются строки вида:

```
for (j,, in 0 ..< entries.count) {
```

Что раньше делала двойная запятая (не вижу в документации ничего такого в разделе про циклы)? И как должна выглядеть эта конструкции в современной версии языка?

Comment: На stackoverflow.com есть подобный вопрос про запятую в цикле for c подтверждением, что в expression list запятая возможна при перечислении условий. for (var i = 0, x = 0; i < 10; i++, x++) { println ("i is (i) x is (x)"); } stackoverflow.com/questions/26348589/… Так что в данном случае запятые можно просто убрать: for j in 0..<entries.count

Comment: @OlgaSamoilova что делают запятые в цикле for, который вы привели в качестве примера (его, кстати, в Swift 3 тоже больше нет) понятно. Мне не понятно что делает двойная запятая в том примере, который привел я. Когда-то раньше этот код компилировался, сейчас нет. Думаете, там должен был быть список переменных? Переменные убрали, а запятые оставили?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что да.  Никаких упоминаний двойных запятых в синтаксисе нет.

Comment: тогда бы это наверное должно было бы выглядеть вот так: for (,,j in 0 ..< entries.count) {

Comment: у меня в этом проекте, который я смотрю, таких циклов с двумя запятыми десятки - вряд ли это косяк, скорее это раньше компилировалось и работало, только я не увидел в документации как это должно было работать и не могу понять почему именно так написано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понял откуда взялась "двойная запятая". При конвертации в современный Swift, Xcode заменил строки вида:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yVals.count; i++) {
```

на:

```
for (i,, in 0 ..< yVals.count) {
```

Я же подумал сначала, что это очередная диковинная конструкция старой версии языка, оказалось просто не слишком корректная автоконвертация.